# How do I escape the Command Line?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

Project Goal:
I want to make a program in C++ with one button that, when pressed, will display "hello world".
Im using Xcode IDE and would like to emulate the app on an iPhone.

Description of Project:
Make a program with one large black or white button, when pressed that says "hello world."

I'm a new programmer learning C++. I'm most of the way through the C++ program on Codecademy and have made some projects on my own through Xcode. I can't figure out how to get my programs out of the command line though! I'd really like to start writing programs with their own screen/panel, accept mouse-inputs, display custom images, etc.

I've read Apple developer articles on how to emulate apps via Xcode, and watched three youtube videos on how to get an emulator to work but haven't come across a good solution yet. Any good video recommendations would be much appreciated.  Or even better, just a quick example code that I could copy, paste, and execute to study!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Xcode project, you pick what kind of application you want. For example MacOS application, iOS application, command line application.

Create a MacOS application, press command-r, and it will run. It won’t do anything useful obviously until you add a code. If you look for tutorials, try to find some rather new ones.

Apples developer website has lots of sample applications. (developer.apple.com)